# Blade templating engine syntax issues on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm currently starting a project on the beta version of [Laravel 4](https://github.com/laravel/framework)

When i try to use the templating engine some tags work and some doesn't. e.g:

```html
@layout('layouts.master')
@section('container')
    <h1>About US</h1>
@endsection
```

is displayed as:

```html
@layout('layouts.master')

About US

@endsection
```

which means that the `@section` tag is parsed, but the other are referred to as plain text.
also if i change the `@layout` to `@include`, it does include the template.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Have there been any syntax changes I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`@layout` has been changed to `@extends` in Laravel 4. Also, `@endsection` has been changed to `@stop`

Comment: Has @include been changed or replaced?

Comment: The [documentation is pretty good](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures).

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is that a lot of tutorials online (youtube and blogs) still use the @layout and @endsection. And these tutorials usually claim to be Laravel4  tutorials as well.

So a lot of people fall in to this little trap starting their first Laravel4 app.

Tip: I use this guy's cheat sheet [page](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca) while developing (propers to Jesse O'Brien). It's how I found out myself I was using outdated blade tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you come across problems with Laravel or in case you don't know if Laravel has built in a functionality you'd need, allways check out the docs for the Laravel version you use.

The **online documentation** of the current released version (4 at the time of writing): http://laravel.com/docs/

and **the Laravel API** to dive into the source online with explanation of e.g. function arguments: http://laravel.com/api/